# Open and Read : Multiple xml files from the Folder python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have stored about 150+ XML files in one folder. I want to open and read those XML files from that folder (about 150+ XML files); after that, I do the next analysis. What do I need to change in the below code to open/read the multiple XML files from that folder?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import pandas as pd 

infile = open("F:\\itprocess\\xmltest.xml","r")
contents = infile.read()
```

Comment: You can use `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()` to find all names in a directory.

Comment: @AKX can you please give me an example?

Comment: You can literally Google for "stackoverflow glob.glob" to find this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python/3964691#3964691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os` module's `listdir()` function is a good way to use while reading multiple files.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import pandas as pd 
import os    

d = os.listdir()
for file in d:
    infile = open(file,"r")
    contents = infile.read()
```

Of course here I am assuming you only have your XML files in your current directory.