# how to parse unstructured xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

How can i parse unstructured xml file? i need to get data inside patient tag and title using elementTree.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd">
<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
<id extension="4b78219a-1d02-4e7c-9870-dc7ce3b8a8fb" root="1.2.840.113619.21.1.3214775361124994304.5.1"/>
<code code="34133-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Summarization of episode note"/>
<title>Summary</title>
<effectiveTime value="20170919160921ddfdsdsdsd31-0400"/>
<confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.dwdwddsd1.113883.5.25"/>
<recordTarget>
<patientRole><id extension="0" root="1.2.840.113619.21.1.3214775361124994304.2.1.1.2"/>
<addr use="HP"><streetAddressLine>addd2 </streetAddressLine><city>fgfgrtt</city><state>tr</state><postalCode>121213434</postalCode><country>rere</country></addr>
<patient>
<name><given>fname</given><family>lname</family></name>
<administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" displayName="Female"/>
<birthTime value="19501025"/>
<maritalStatusCode code="M" codeSystem="2434.16.840.1.143434313883.5.2" displayName="M"/>
<languageCommunication>
<languageCode code="eng"/>
<proficiencyLevelCode nullFlavor="NI"/>
<preferenceInd value="true"/>
</languageCommunication>
</patient>
```

i want given name , family name , gender and title.

Comment: Beautifull soup can handle bad xml https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup` bs4 and `lxml` parser library to **scrape** xml data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd">
<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
<id extension="4b78219a-1d02-4e7c-9870-dc7ce3b8a8fb" root="1.2.840.113619.21.1.3214775361124994304.5.1"/>
<code code="34133-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Summarization of episode note"/>
<title>Summary</title>
<effectiveTime value="20170919160921ddfdsdsdsd31-0400"/>
<confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.dwdwddsd1.113883.5.25"/>
<recordTarget>
<patientRole><id extension="0" root="1.2.840.113619.21.1.3214775361124994304.2.1.1.2"/>
<addr use="HP"><streetAddressLine>addd2 </streetAddressLine><city>fgfgrtt</city><state>tr</state><postalCode>121213434</postalCode><country>rere</country></addr>
<patient>
<name><given>fname</given><family>lname</family></name>
<administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" displayName="Female"/>
<birthTime value="19501025"/>
<maritalStatusCode code="M" codeSystem="2434.16.840.1.143434313883.5.2" displayName="M"/>
<languageCommunication>
<languageCode code="eng"/>
<proficiencyLevelCode nullFlavor="NI"/>
<preferenceInd value="true"/>
</languageCommunication>
</patient>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, "lxml")

title = soup.find("title")
print(title.text.strip())

patient = soup.find("patient")
given = patient.find("given").text.strip()
family = patient.find("family").text.strip()
gender = patient.find("administrativegendercode")['displayname'].strip()

print(given)
print(family)
print(gender)
```

O/P:

```
Summary
fname
lname
Female
```

**Install library dependency:**

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
pip3 install lxml==4.3.3
```

Comment: what is the best way to read multiple xml files from folder using python?

Comment: @prasanna try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247468/open-and-read-multiple-xml-files-from-the-folder-python

Comment: it is working fine, Thank You. but this python program is expecting both file and xml file must be in same folder??

Comment: i am getting this error 'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './user/root/SQP/raw_ccd/*'' in linux.

Comment: @prasanna Please ask a new question, what you have tried python code with an error message.

Comment: above parsing can i do using elementTree? facing some issue with BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use lxml. Here is tutorial that I used: https://lxml.de/tutorial.html
But it should be similar to:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.Element("patient")
print(root.find("given"))
print(root.find("family"))
print(root.find("give"))
```

Comment: all the values are printing none.

Comment: all values are printing none. please suggest me.

Comment: Have you tried xpath with lxml? Here you have link to my github:
https://github.com/kkarczewski/xml_operation/blob/master/xml_modify/xml_operation.py

Try with first function `get_element(path, xpath)`.

Comment: you can modify that function to read text from string. Instead of 
`tree = etree.parse(path) 
root = tree.getroot()` you can use `root = etree.fromstring(xml)`

Comment: still i am getting None only.

Comment: etree.parse(path) is printing complete xml file multiple times (centos or linux).